# HTML not Sending Data to Java File

Tags: java, html, http, io

So I've had a bit of experience with front-end web dev and much experience with OOP (with Java), but I have never worked with processing user input from an HTML form and doing something with that data. Since I've had so much experience with Java, I figured that would be the best language to work with. What I am trying to do is collect user data from a form (basic stuff: name, address, etc) and process it in a Java file. Right now, I don't think the data is even being sent over to the Java file, as when I click the "Submit" button, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Lob Application</title>

<link href = "bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<link href = "stylesheet.css" rel = "stylesheet" >
</head>

<body>
<div id = formInput class = "container-fluid">
<form name = "submitDataForm" method = "post" action = "processData">
  Name:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "name"><br>
  Address Line 1:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "addressLineOne"><br>
  Address Line 2:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "addressLineTwo"><br>
  City:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "city"><br>
  State:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "state"><br>
  Zip Code:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "zip"><br>
  Message:<br>
    <input type = "text" name = "message"><br>
  <input id = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Submit"
</form>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

processData.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/processData")
public class processData extends HttpServlet{
public static void main(String[] args){}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException{
String name = req.getParameter("name");
String address1 = req.getParameter("addressLineOne");
String address2 = req.getParameter("addressLineTwo");
String city = req.getParameter("city");
String state = req.getParameter("state");
String zip = req.getParameter("zip");
String message = req.getParameter("message");

System.out.println("city: " + city);

PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();

String htmlResponse = "<html>";
htmlResponse += "<h2>Your city is: " + city +"<br/>";
htmlResponse += "</html>";

writer.println(htmlResponse);
}
}
```

Comment: Check browser console for any errors also network tab whether request is sent or not.

Comment: How would I do that, I'm not sure what either of those things mean :/

Comment: If you are using chrome then click on three vertical dots icon which is used to open setting. A window will open in this go to more tools and select developer tools. A new window will open. In this select console tab. Here all error messages are printed. Also there is network tab which shows all request sent from browser.

Comment: How are you running this program? Servlets do not work by themselves, they need to run in a web server.

Comment: @immibis right now I am just running it locally on my PC by opening index.html in Chrome. When I click the submit button, nothing happens.

Comment: @CarterKlein That will not work.

Comment: Why? Is there any way I can test this program then?

Comment: If you know how HTML forms work (they send the data to a web server over HTTP) then you'll know why you need a web server.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I knew everything about how HTML forms work. I'll look it up somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

seeing your html code your code for submit button is not correct, input tag is not closed

your code

```
<input id = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Submit"
```

correct should be

```
<input id = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
```